# Jenkins + Grunt on Windows = constant EBUSY and ENOENT errors

Tags: node.js, jenkins, gruntjs, windows-server-2008-r2, yui-compressor

Trying to build a branch in Jenkins. Build always fails, usually after getting one file processed, but sometimes at a random point in the list of files to min/concat.

Errors look like:

```
"ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\grunt-minify-concat Build\workspace\1419346881831"
```

or

```
"EBUSY, resource busy or locked 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\grunt-minify-concat Build\workspace\1419370631016'"
```

grunt-minify-concat is a branch of the project where we've added a few lines to Grunt, adding a task for CSS/JS concatenation and minification. Very standard stuff. Here are the relevant bits of the config:

Gruntfile.js

```
cssmin: {
  dist: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'MySite.Web/css/',
    src: ['*.css', '!*.min.css'],
    dest: 'MySite.Web/css/',
    ext: '.min.css'
  }
},

min: {
  dist : {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'MySite.Web/',
    src : [
      'js/*.js',
      'scripts/*.js',
      '!js/*.min.js',
      '!scripts/*.min.js',
      '!js/jquery*.js',
      '!scripts/jquery*.js'
    ],
    dest : 'MySite.Web/js/',
    ext: '.min.js'
  }
}

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-yui-compressor');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-msbuild');

grunt.registerTask('build', ['sass', 'cssmin', 'min' , 'msbuild:sln', 'copy:libraryDll']);

grunt.registerTask('buildserver', ['version', 'build', 'tag', 'push', 'output']);

grunt.registerTask('default', ['build']);
```

packages.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "~0.8.1",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-yui-compressor": "0.1.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.1.3",
    "grunt-exec": "~0.4.3",
    "grunt-msbuild": "~0.1.9",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0"
},
```

I've applied a hotfix to the Windows 2008R2 server that hosts Jenkins, resolving the path length issue. However, I still get the EBUSY issue. Google and other forums suggest that these are Windows quirks that will not be fixed any time soon.

Is this normal? I'm usually on Ruby where Sprockets is automagically doing all of this. I am relatively new to Grunt and Jenkins, but this seems to be textbook Grunt-101 stuff that should just work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, msbuild processes like to hang around. Sometimes I have to run `taskkill /im msbuild.exe /f /t` manually.

Answer (score -1):

There is a decent chance you have one of your files open in Microsoft Word or another random non-programming editor. Word locks up access to the file. Completely exit MS Word and re-build. Fixed the problem for me. Hope it helps!